# Why does one Mysa smart thermostat override the others?

Tags: thermostat, baseboard

[image]I installed a Mysa smart thermostat in our master bedroom to control our baseboard heater. There are three other analog thermostats on the same floor (bedroom, office, bathroom). Today we noticed that, even when the analog units were cranked, there is no heat. I flipped and reset the breakers just to check if that was the culprit. No dice. Still cold.

So I increased the temp on the Mysa in the master bedroom, and now all three rooms with cold baseboards and analog thermostats are hot. How is this possible?

Comment: We'd need to see your wiring to help. Please add detailed descriptions, diagrams, and/or photos.

Answer (score 1):

You're somehow bypassing the other thermostats and have their load wires tapped into your new thermostat. Verify your wiring. Return it to its original state and investigate further.
..